# Released Flutter application crashes on launch

Tags: android, flutter

EDIT: 
The solution to this problem is upgrading your flutter version to a dev build newer then.1.7.0. You can also upload seperate APK versions but I personally disliked this option. Do make sure you dont download a "bad build" from the flutter github dev repo since then you'll get even more problems you'll have to fix. 1.8.0 is the one I used.

Whenever I run the debug or release version of my flutter application from android studio on my phone it works. I just released a private test of my application on the Google Play Store but now my application won't even launch. It gives me the following error in the logs:

```
E/flutter (17419): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_data.cc(19)] VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings.
E/flutter (17419): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(241)] Could not setup VM data to bootstrap the VM from.
E/flutter (17419): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_lifecycle.cc(89)] Could not create Dart VM instance.
F/flutter (17419): [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(218)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
```

I have upgraded all my plugins, flutter and gradle versions to the most recent ones and the app still runs fine when I run it from my computer. I have already used the `flutter clean` command and tried running the app on multiple physical devices, without success.

My app is a native flutter application (I saw another topic with a similar problem but that solution didn't work because my app is a native flutter application and theirs was not) and I used `flutter build appbundle` to generate the bundle.

Anyone else encountered such a problem and know how to fix this?

Comment: post stack trace here.

Comment: Try pulling a fresh copy of the project from your repo, run `flutter clean` then `flutter run`

Comment: same issue i face ...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by uploading the APK instead of the App Bundle.

I don't know why the App Bundle didn't work, but I am certain that this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Right Now .apk is the only solution.

App bundle is not working on 6.0 android devices

[image]

You can Discuss more at : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147096055

The recommended solution is to use `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` instead of app bundles.

Hope they fix it ASAP.