# Flutter crash after installed in my android phone from Google play

Tags: flutter

I have a strange problem if you have any idea thank you a lot.
When I compile my application directly in my android photo it's ok
When I install this application from Google Play is open and close immediately and I dont know
why? and how can I do to debug this situation.

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802791/released-flutter-application-crashes-on-launch does this help?

Comment: Hello Thank you

Comment: Did it work? Then I can answer your question and get accepted